# Common attack vectors for Microsoft Exchange Server?

Tags: windows, iis, attack-vector, exchange

What are the common attack vectors for a **Microsoft Exchange Server**?

My online searches only yield discussion into various APT groups, and technical write-ups of different 0day exploits. There does not seem to be an OWASP top 10 vulnerabilities, nor any threats that appear to be commonly used.

Unless it is a common attack vector, side channel attacks (those involving measurements like timing) are outside the scope of my question.

This is not for academic research, so anything even partially reputable will be fine.

Comment: Microsoft Exchange Server is THE common attack vector for the corporate networks.

Comment: The question is undefined. On-prem? Cloud? The binary itself? How are you defining "common"? How do you differentiate between Exchange and IIS? This is sounding like, and this perception is backed up by your bounty comment, that you are asking "how do I hack Exchange?". That's too undefined to answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft Sxchange server is basically an MTA (Mail Transfer Agent), you can find all the relevant information on the supported protocols on [Exchange Server Protocol Documents](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxprotlp/30c90a39-9adf-472b-8b5b-03c282304a83). In general, MTAs have exposed SMTP and POP3 and IMAP protocols, and those are the relevant common attack vectors for MTAs.